# Rank points based off the highest number in a row

Tags: php, mysql, function, rank

I have a table called "member_points", which is set up like this:

```
|----|-------|----------|------------------------|
| id |  uid  |  points  |  last_loggedin         |
|----|-------|----------|------------------------|
| 1  |  1    |  5075    |  2012-08-02 02:04:00   |
|----|-------|----------|------------------------|
| 2  |  2    |  2026    |  2012-08-04 02:15:02   |
|----|-------|----------|------------------------|
```

I have a function below. I want the function to echo or return the rank like "Ranked #1" or "Ranked #2", based on the number in the row "points".

```
function getTopRanks($id) {  
   $sql = "SELECT MAX(points) AS toppoints FROM member_points";
   $r = mysql_query($sql);
   if ( $r !== false && mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
      while ( $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {
          $points = stripslashes($a['toppoints']);
          return ''.$points.'';  
      }
   }
}
```

Can someone help me make this possible?

Comment: Do you want to sum the points of every login a user had, or just the login with the highest points?

Comment: I want a way to make the function say like, "this user is ranked #1" (or what ever number they are) based from the number of points each user has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are going to ranking user on the basis of **points**. 
For such type of problem, i suggest you to first rank *user* on **DESC** order. Then pickup desire value form row.

```
function getTopRanks($id) {

   $sql = "SELECT uid FROM member_points ORDER BY points DESC ";
   $r = mysql_query($sql);
   if ( $r !== false && mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
      while ( $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {
         $points = stripslashes($a['toppoints']);

           return ''.$points.'';

     }
   }

 }
```

this will solve your problem.:)

**UPDATE AS YOUR REQUIREMENTS:**

```
function getTopRanksUser($id) {
$userPos ="Ranked position is:";
  $count = 0;
  $sql = "SELECT uid FROM member_points ORDER BY points DESC ";
  $r = mysql_query($sql);
  if ( $r !== false && mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
    while ( $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {
       $count = $count+1;
       $userPosCount = $userPos+$count;

       return $userPosCount;

  }
 }

}
```

there should be return userPos+count. because count is increases up number of rows in table and the string *ranked position is* always remains same. 
this will give result. Your can change return string according to your requirements. :)
thanks.

Comment: Yes this helps! Thanks, and do you know of a way to make the function say like, this user is ranked #1 (or what ever number they are) based from the number of points?

Comment: that means, you want to rank those user?

Comment: @Dalton make me some clear about requirements. actually where are you  implementing this code ? what is your project?

Comment: I'm making a site that allow users to signup and login. Every time someone does, it'll give the user "points". I have that done and it's working. (Everything will go on the user's public profile.) I have it to where it says the users points on their profile, So now I'm trying to do is make it say which user is ranked in what place. SO like, if the user has 443 points, and is the 3rd highest from having the most points, the function will echo or return "Ranked 3rd". I hope this better understands what I'm trying to do.

Comment: i update my answer. this will help.
here, you should not worry about points, only concern with position on table. :)

Comment: i think,there is not necessary to pass $id there.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Could you explain a little more please? :/

Comment: It says that both users are ranked at number 1.

Comment: Also, I use $id in the function to pull only the user I'm using the profile for.

Comment: Could I use a array to put the values in from mysql and use php to find the highest number and echo rank that way?

Comment: yes, you can use array to store $userId. then use that array to show result.

Answer (score 3):

In your mysql query use ORDER BY (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

so your query would become

```
SELECT points FROM member_points ORDER BY points DESC
```

this will sort the results from the query by the amount of points. (DESC will make them descending and ASC will make the result ascending).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use for my rankings ... this code also takes into account ties and displays correctly. Just change "username" and "points" to your appropriate column names in your db and set the db connection vars: $hostName $databaseNanme $username and $password for you connection.

Hope this helps!

```
    $sql1 = "SET @rnk=0; SET @rank=0; SET @scount=0;";
    $sql2 = "SELECT username, points, rank FROM
    (
        SELECT AA.*,BB.username, points
        (@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk,
        (@rank:=IF(@scount=points,@rank,@rnk)) rank,
        (@scount:=points) newscount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT COUNT(1) scorecount,points
            FROM users GROUP BY points
        ) AAA
        ORDER BY points DESC
    ) AA LEFT JOIN users BB USING (points)) A;";

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostName.';dbname='.$databaseName, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->query($sql1);
    $data = $conn->query($sql2);

    $standings = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log( 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage() );
}
```

print_r($standings);